# How do you change the caret to the insert type (a flashing box instead of a flashing line) in a textbox in C#?

Tags: c#-4.0, textbox

I've set textbox.InsertKeyMode = InsertKeyMode.Overwrite and now I want the caret to change to the traditional flashing box.

How do I do this?

Thanks!

Isaac

Answer (score 1):

There is no managed support for dealing with carets in the .NET Framework.
You'll have to use p/invoke to change the caret:

Carets: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/winui/winui/windowsuserinterface/resources/carets.asp

http://pinvoke.net is a valuable resource when using p/invoke.

Comment: That's not the answer I wanted to hear. Why is it so annoying to do simple things sometimes? Thanks though! Will accept if it works.